# How can i convert my variable to the parameter type of predict method in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predict

I have to predict an input with my random forest model clf as below:

```
y_predict_test = clf.predict(input)
```

the type of input is a string and its value is generated by a function.

```
print input
[  6.36505950e+10   6.36505951e+10   6.32830000e+01 ...,   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
```

The predict method do not accept a string as parameter.

What type to use to convert the variable input ? and how to convert it ?

Maybe i have to ask my question in another way.

I have to convert the variable input to an array with dtype float64.

the variable input is as below:

```
print input
[  6.36505950e+10   6.36505951e+10   6.32830000e+01 ...,   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]

FV = np.array(input)
print FV
[  6.36505950e+10   6.36505951e+10   6.32830000e+01 ...,   0.00000000e+00
0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]

print type (FV)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print FV.dtype
|S109
```

As you can see, elements type of FV array is |S109. How can i convert elements type to float64 ?

I tried :

```
FV = np.array(featureVector, dtype=np.float64)
```

but it doesn't work.

thank you for your help,

Comment: Can you run `type(input)` to make sure it is a string? Also, the function returning it should probably actually return a numpy array. Seems like a bug to me that it returns a string.

Comment: the result of type(input) is <type 'str'>. In fact, the input variable is received by a messaging protocol. the content of the message is systematically converted to a string.

Comment: Then the bug is in the sender. The array is not properly serialized.

Comment: Use the same method to convert your string `input` as you used to convert your strings from your training data. Don't know what you are using to vectorize your strings but if it's a build-in sklearn function just use something like `extr = feature_extraction_method.fit(your_training_data)` on your training data and then on your `input` variable `vectorized_input = extr.transform(input)`

Comment: The predict method takes a ndarray type as parameter type. How can i convert the input variable to ndarray type ?

Comment: As i already mentioned: You should do this in the same way you converted your training data. Before you can call `predict` on a classifier you must already have trained it. So if you have come this far already I may assume you have done some converting of strings for training?

Comment: You can build a ndarray from a string with [`np.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) (or [`np.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html), [`np.fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html), ...). However, your strings do not contain complete arrays (see the ellipsis `...`), so you will not be able to recover the original array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the print do not displau all elements of input variable because there many elements (38 elements). I used np.fromstring: FV = np.fromstring(featureVector, dtype=np.float64, sep=' ') but the result is: [] an empty array